# SQL JOINT and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have 2 tables:

- r1 : with primary key k1 ;
- r2 : whih secondary key k1 (from r1 table) duplicate authorised

r2 can therefore have several line having k1 as secondary key on which a SUM, for instance could be perform.

My problem is that when I try

```
select
  r1.col_n,
  sum(r2.col_m),
  **count(*)as total**
from
  r1,r2
where
  r1.k1 = r2.k1
```

The COUNT(*) here will return the number of occurence or r2.k1  I understand this is what it is suppose to do and thats what the query means.

My problem is (and dont ask me why because lots of secondary keys are in r1... lol) I would like the COUNT(*) to return me the number of occurrence of r1.k1 in that joint query instead of r2.k1  ... I need the sum(r2.col_m) and the count(*) on r1...

Could you guyz help me here ?

Comment: Please only tag your question with the SQL database you are using.

Comment: I always love to smoke my SQL joint ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DISTINCT:

```
select
  r1.col_n,
  sum(r2.col_m),
  count(DISTINCT r1.k1) as total
from
  r1 INNER JOIN r2 ON r1.k1 = r2.k1
```

- COUNT(*) will count all rows (all rows from r1 multiplied for all rows from r2 where the join succeeds)
- COUNT(r1.k1) will count all rows where r1.k1 is not null, but still multiplied for all rows from r2 where the join succeeds
- COUNT(DISTINCT r1.k1) will count all distinct values of r1.k1

there are other alternatives (e.g. using a subquery where you do the counts, then join this subquery with r2) but COUNT(DISTINCT r1.k1) should be enough for your question.

Also, it's better to use a JOIN so i converted:

```
FROM r1, r2
WHERE r1.k1=r2.k2
```

with this syntax:

```
FROM
  r1 INNER JOIN r2
  ON r1.k1=r2.k2
```

Comment: AWESOME bro it works...I know DISTINCT but may I ask what I am missing here ?

Comment: @MichaelJohnson hi, I've updated my answer and added more details, pls let me know if it's all clear

Comment: okay....I had no idea COUNT was that ''smart''...I though it'd only count the number of occurence of a given item in a SELECT result set. When you said ___COUNT(DISTINCT r1.k1) will count all distinct values of r1.k1__ I understand it means distinct values of r1.k1 found in r2.k1. It I understood it right then it all makes perfect sense for me now.  Thank you again...especially for explaining the details.

Comment: I found http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx   it's all clear now. Thank you again